# What is the purpose of Windows style flags like WS_TILED and WS_ICONIC that are just renaming of others? (Windows/C++)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-style-flags

I was looking at the various windows styles flags, and I noticed that a few flags are defined as such:

```
#define WS_TILED            WS_OVERLAPPED
#define WS_ICONIC           WS_MINIMIZE
#define WS_SIZEBOX          WS_THICKFRAME
#define WS_TILEDWINDOW      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
```

What is the purpose of defining new flags that are literally identical to other flags?

Comment: Note: WS_TILED = WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000L, which is not useful as flag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its purpose is backwards compatibility.  WS_TILED and WS_ICONIC probably date back to Windows version 1.

One of Microsoft's great burdens, once they put a #define or function in an SDK header file, they can *never* delete it again.

Comment: A further question could be: "Why they had renamed then in next versions"?

Comment: @Luca: nothing got renamed, these styles just don't exist anymore.  They are getting mapped to the closest existing equivalent.